# PHP - custom error log new lines

Tags: php, ini, error-log

I have a web site hosted at a provider.

I have put a custom php.ini at my webroot, which sets my custom error_log file:

```
error_log = /home/mysite/public_html/php-errors.log
error_append_string = "\r\n"
```

However, php-errors.log is not formatting new lines

```
[24-Jan-2015 14:54:16 Europe/London] blah[24-Jan-2015 15:53:53 Europe/London] foo
```

Instead, I want this:

```
[24-Jan-2015 14:54:16 Europe/London] blah
[24-Jan-2015 15:53:53 Europe/London] foo
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Did you restart apache after making that change?

Comment: no need for restarting apache and no need for `\r\n`, just use `\n` alone.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot restart my provider's server. I also tried "\n" and "\\r\\n", but still no luck. My provider said "This file can take a few hours before it starts receiving errors". Think I'll have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

In my own custom error log I use `\n` and that works fine. Alternatively use a carridge return in your IDE so you save data in the form

```
$dataToBeSavedToLog = $data1." something
else
in new lines";
```

and that will save including the new lines.